# How to pass a pointer to LuaJIT ffi to be used as out argument?

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit

Assuming there is following C code:

```c
struct Foo { int dummy; }
int tryToAllocateFoo(Foo ** dest);
```

...How to do following in LuaJIT?

```c
Foo * pFoo = NULL;
tryToAllocateFoo(&pFoo);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
local ffi = require 'ffi'

ffi.cdef [[
  struct Foo { int dummy; };
  int tryToAllocateFoo(Foo ** dest);
]]

local theDll = ffi.load(dllName)

local pFoo = ffi.new 'struct Foo *[1]'
local ok = theDll.tryToAllocateFoo(pFoo)

if ok == 0 then -- Assuming it returns 0 on success
  print('dummy ==', pFoo[0].dummy)
end
```

Comment: Aha! You have to use `[1]` instead of a second `*`! Makes sense, but takes some getting used to.